# synchronously execute the processing flow of data on DataFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to do batch processing to perform BigQuery's data processing complicatedly using DataFlow and store it in another table of BigQuery.

Specifically, it is such a process.

Read data from BigQuery → Dofn processing → Combine processing → Flatten processing → Combine processing → Flatten processing → Write data to Bigquery.

This process moves as intended by DirectRunner (Local), but when executed with DataFlowRunner (GCP), since each Ptransform is executed asynchronously, the Combine process is executed even though reading of data is not finished It will not move seriously, such as.

How can I synchronously execute the processing flow of data on DataFlow?

Comment: If your input is bounded source (which is BQ), then to me combine will start only after DoFn process is done. Are you sure you are seeing combine processes even reading has not finished?

Comment: yes !   I seeing combine processes even reading has not finished.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly define bounded data source?

Comment: You may get more help if you provide an example program that demonstrates the problem.  I have a Python job that reads from BigQuery using `beam.io.BigQuerySource`, and it behaves as expected.